# How to multiply sql values by 5 and update a value in a column

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I made sqlite database and populated it with values and multiply by 5 and update the its column value. I tried this :

```
String sql = "UPDATE "+TABLE_NAME +" SET " + ColumnName+ " WHERE ( SELECT " + "("+ColumnName * 5 +")"+ " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "+id+ " = "+Id + ")";
```

To be more clear I need to fetch `ColumnName` value and multiply by `5` with `ColumnName` then update `ColumnName` with new value.

I am not sure that it is correct way.

Comment: Have you tired your code?What is your issue?

Comment: You might need to get the column name before you run the sql statement, but seeing your code will help

Comment: error with multiply 5 in sql statement. This the correct approach?

Comment: But i need to update multiple row according to id.

Comment: Try "UPDATE "+TABLE_NAME +" SET " + ColumnName+ " = "+5+"* (SELECT " + "("+ColumnName +")"+ " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "+id+ " = "+Id + ") WHERE "+id+ " = "+Id + ";

Comment: The SQL statement should look like `UPDATE tname SET colname=5*colname WHERE id=10`. (replace the table and column names and id as necessary.)

Comment: @E.Abdel This worked.